# Read word Doc. using c#

Tags: c#, dll, ms-word

I have created an application. The text in the rich textbox is stored in word doc. using word interop dll. Now i want to read the word doc back to my richtextbox.

I used  `oDoc.Content.Text` to read. Its working but the alignment is not there. I need to load with the same alingment in the word doc.

And also i used **this code**

```
oDoc.Activate();
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy()
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
txtdocument.Text = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
       .GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

But it throws this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Is your program single threaded apartment? If not the `Clipboard` class will not work.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject.aspx)

> The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.

Comment: I tried to set STAThreadAttribute 
But it throws this error Failed to set the specified COM apartment state.

Comment: @jafrywilson: Did you use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState`? If so you need to instead add [STAThread] in front of your Main() deceleration.

Comment: My method is this
 [STAThread]
    private void ReadWordDoc()
     {    
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass oWordApplic = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();

Comment: string strFilePath = "D:\\wilson\\tms\\Documents\\IND2011-2012\\TB_CNR_IND_270520114946.doc";
 object objFile = strFilePath;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
         object objReadOnly = false;
         object visiblity = true;

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = oWordApplic.Documents.Open(ref objFile, ref missing, ref objReadOnly,
              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
              ref missing, ref missing, ref visiblity, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
         oDoc.Activate();
        //txtdocument.Text = oDoc.Content.Text;
        oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
 Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Comment: IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
txtdocument.Text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
}

Comment: I got this error
Failed to set the specified COM apartment state.

Comment: When setting the current thread's property SetApartmentState, try using Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA); let us know if it works..

Comment: if it still doesnt work..see my new EDIT on the previous answer. try that piece of code and let us know.

Comment: `[STAThread]` needs to be on your main method, aka the one that starts your program, not the method in question. Unless this is happening on a different thread in which case you should use `SetApartmentState` before starting it up, you cannot change apartment state of a running thread (well you can, but it won't do anything)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that `Clipboard.GetDataObject();` returns a null reference and then in the very last line you try to access its member

```
txtdocument.Text = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

Anyway just as a suggestion, why you dont replace the last line

```
txtdocument.Text = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

with this:

```
txtdocument.Text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

EDIT: check if either one of your variables oDoc, txtDocument, or data is null..

NEW EDIT :

```
Thread tempThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadstuff))
tempThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
tempThread.Start();
```

Comment: In this line the data objet returns null value              IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

Comment: That's my point. It is why it throws the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error..Can you show the part of the code where you created a new instance of Thread and called the member method SetApartmentState?

Comment: for the previous answer i replied my method